# How to add or modify android graphical layout palette

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, palette

I want to add set of custom components in Android Graphical Palette with the name given by me and I want to include separate implementation for those components.For example if I drag and drop any component from that particular set one more tab should add apart from Graphical layout and xml_name.xml and that should contain .c code for that xml which I have to write.

Can any one please explain how do these all these things where should I include my code for generating .c code from xml and all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no currently supported Eclipse for Android at the moment. Google is no longer supporting Eclipse, and Eclipse's Andmore project is still a work-in-progress at the present time. Beyond that, your question is much too broad, as writing an IDE plugin is a not the sort of thing that can be answered in a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Fine with Android studio as well

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html